# How to get ERROR list from this JSON object in React js?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

How to get ERROR list from this JSON object in React js?

```
data = {
     "container_1587015390439_0001_01_000004": {
       "ERROR":["20/04/16 05:43:51 ERROR CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM"]
       ,
       "WARN": [],
       "INFO": []
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean without knowing the container code?

For the first:

```js
data = {
  "container_1587015390439_0001_01_000004": {
    "ERROR": ["20/04/16 05:43:51 ERROR CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM"],
    "WARN": [],
    "INFO": []
  }
}
console.log(data[Object.keys(data)[0]].ERROR.join(";"));
```

For more:

```js
data = {
  "container_1587015390439_0001_01_000001": {
    "ERROR": ["20/04/16 05:35:51 ERROR CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM"],
    "WARN": [],
    "INFO": []
  },
  "container_1587015390439_0001_01_000002": {
    "ERROR": ["20/04/16 05:43:51 ERROR CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM"],
    "WARN": [],
    "INFO": []
  }
}
let errors = Object.keys(data).map(key => data[key].ERROR.join(";")).join("\n");
console.log(errors)
// OR
errors = Object.values(data).map(item => item.ERROR).join("\n");
console.log(errors);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate `objects` and collect all errors.

`Flat` is util to flatten the array of array
`join` can be used to contact all string.

```js
const data = {"container_1587015390439_0001_01_000004":{"ERROR":["20/04/16 05:43:51 ERROR CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM"],"WARN":[],"INFO":[]},"container_1587015390439_01010000004":{"ERROR":["20/01/12 05:43:51 ERROR CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: RECEIVED SIGNAL PUSH"],"WARN":[],"INFO":[]}};

const flat = (arr = []) => [].concat(...arr);
let errors = Object.values(data).map((d) => d.ERROR);
console.log(errors); // array of errors
errors = flat(Object.values(data).map((d) => d.ERROR));
console.log(errors); // flat of errors
errors = errors.join("\n");
console.log(errors); // join all
```

Using flatMap:

```js
const data = {"container_1587015390439_0001_01_000004":{"ERROR":["20/04/16 05:43:51 ERROR CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM", "20/04/16 05:43:51 ERROR Something: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM"],"WARN":[],"INFO":[]},"container_1587015390439_01010000004":{"ERROR":["20/01/12 05:43:51 ERROR CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: RECEIVED SIGNAL PUSH"],"WARN":[],"INFO":[]}};

let errors = Object.values(data).map((d) => d.ERROR).flatMap(x => x); 
errors = errors.join("\n"); 
console.log(errors);
```

Comment: Why the elaborate scripts? and why reinvent .flat() / .flatMap() ?

Comment: Same result: `let errors = Object.values(data).map((d) => d.ERROR);
errors = errors.join("\n");
console.log(errors); // join all`

Comment: @mplungjan: added detail.
And out put wont be same if `ERROR: ["20/04/16 05:43:51 ERROR CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM", "20/04/16 05:43:51 ERROR Something: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM"]`

Output will have `,` in it not `\n`